# How is adipose tissue synthesized?

Tags: body-fat, energy

I am wondering about how the food that we eat gets converted to adipose tissue.  A great many articles are explaining how fat (the macronutrient) gets converted to energy but there are very few (at least to my understanding) that explain how energy gets converted to fat (adipose tissue).  What are some of the factors that affect the conversion of energy to fat?  Does the number of fat cells multiply or do they simply get bigger?  I would like a simple answer, for a quick reference, and a deeper explanation, for further research on my part.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. I think your question would be more appropriate on [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) but they have the same prior research requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of carbohydrate which we intake determine the activity of various enzymes involved in this [glycolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycolysis) and [lipogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipogenesis). And high carbohydrate diet directly activates the genes responsible fatty acid synthesis.

In tissues where Malate cycle works, the fat synthesis mainly depends on the metabolic state of cell. Fat synthesis results in production of ATP, so this pathway depends on tissue's ability to use ATP. And defect in this regulation effects this malate cycle and this cell's metabolic energy responsible for rate limiting does not maintain this biosynthesis and results in fat synthesis in adipose tissue.

**Reference:**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3096021/

https://www.jlr.org/content/11/2/131.full.pdf